# Azure Function async/await doesn't work?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I need Azure Function to run every 5 minutes to process the data. There are 2 log entries that I expect, but I only get the first one when I execute in the cloud. When I run this function locally (F5 from VS), everything works as expected.

```
[FunctionName("ProcessData")]
public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo t, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    var processor = new Processor();
    await processor.ProcessAsync();
    log.Info($"Successfully executed");
}
```

The main concern is that function monitor always shows green checkmark. No errors whatsoever, but I keep getting only the first log record and never the last one. I never use `.Result` or `.Wait()`, I don't think I blocked the thread in any way.

I use latest nuget package `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.6`. Tried with older `1.0.2` same difference...

Any ideas?

Comment: At a first glance, I don't see anything wrong with the code. Can you share more about what ProcessAsync is doing? If you can share your function name directly or privately (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately) we could also take a look at  logs. 
What logs are you seeing and what logs are you missing (and where are you looking at the logs)?

Comment: @FabioCavalcante I think I have an idea now. It uses TCP port 2195 to send push notification to apple devices, but this port must be closed by a firewall. This is just a theory as I see a green checkmark and no error in the monitoring... Is there a way to open outbound TCP port for azure function?

Comment: In general,  outbound connections from Functions should be allowed. You may be running into other issues, but your function app name would help narrow it down

Comment: @FabioCavalcante same code works great on AWS lambda.